# Load Balancing using Iptables for UDP

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, nat

I have 3 VMs.
**VM-A  VM-B  VM-C**

Whenever any incoming traffic comes to udp port 9110 of VM-A, How can I equally divide and redirect that traffic using **NAT (MASQUERADE)**

Like for eg if incoming traffic on VM-A on udp port 9110 is 20mbps, the traffic divides equally and gets redirected to VM-B and VM-C as 10mbps each.

I searched a lot on web but could not get anything relevant. Can anyone please help me here

Comment: Is the use of iptables required? I suspect [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/blog/announcing-udp-load-balancing/) would be an easier solution to load balancing UDP traffic.

Comment: I can redirect using ngnix? @PrestonManess

Comment: You can *load-balance*, yes. Nginx will distribute traffic between the two VMs according to the load balancing algorithm that is configured. If you mean something else when you say "redirect," then I'm not sure whether or not nginx will meet your requirements.